# Align text right and center in same div

Tags: html, css

Is it posible to do this in single div? Im trying to make this as simple as possible.

[image]

Most important think is that "Yes", "No" and "2 out of 2" need to be centered, regardless of the amount of text on the left side.

```css
.compliance {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  }
.compliance h5 {
  display: inline-block;
}
.compliance h5:last-child {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="compliance">
    <h5>Breaches</h5>
    <h5>(2014-FY)</h5>
    <h5>No</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="compliance">
    <h5>Cortex test successuful</h5>
    <h5>(2014-FY)</h5>
    <h5>Yes</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="compliance">
    <h5>Training as Nov 15</h5>
    <h5>(2014-FY)</h5>
    <h5>2 out of 2</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Frankly this looks like tabular data...why not use a table?

Comment: That's some crazy misuse of [heading elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements).

Comment: @Paulie_D I was thinking about that also, if this is not possible

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yhtkfkxj/

Comment: @Paulie_D Good thinking, but (2014-FY) need to be exactly beside 1st <h5> like on picture

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u5kdgwuz/ like this?

Comment: @G.L.P Yes, but there is a problem, "Yes", "No" and "2 out of 2" are not centered. I update picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u5kdgwuz/3/)**

```
.compliance {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
.compliance span {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:auto;
    float:left;
}
.compliance span+span {
    padding:0 5px;
    font-weight:normal;
    display: inline;
}
.compliance span:last-child {
    width:30%;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    float:right;
}
.cf:before, .cf:after {
    content:" ";
    display: table;
}
.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="compliance cf"> <span>Cortex test successuful</span>
   <span>(2014-FY)</span>  <span>Yes</span>
 </div>
```